# Solve coupled equations of three variables

Tags: calculus

I have following three coupled equations with three unknowns:

$a+b+c=x,$

$ab+ac+bc=y,$

$abc=z$

Here $a,b,c$ are the unknowns. I tried solving these by substituting $a$ from first equation to third equation and then solve for $b$, which again I put in second equation and solve for $c$. But ultimately I end up in the scenario where the solutions look like $(...)^{1/3}$ which I don't want. I want solutions without any cube root. Is there any clever way to find the unknowns $a,b$ and $c$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Thanks. But the page you referred doesn't say anything about the procedure to obtain the solutions. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Since $a,\,b,\,c$ are the roots of $t^3-xt^2+yt-z=0$, you need to solve this cubic in $t$. [It can be done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula), but the result is messy. Note that $a,\,b,\,c$ are determined only up to a permutation. For example, in the case $x=0,\,y=-1,\,z=0$, we can show only that $a,\,b,\,c$ are $-1,\,0,\,1$ in some order.

Comment: Yeah.....but still I can't get rid of cube root.

Comment: @user108357 The roots are what they are. With $x=z=0,\,y=-2$, the roots would be $-\sqrt[3]{2},\,0,\,\sqrt[3]{2}$.